# NOT OR in regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to make a (nginx) `regex` rule to filter **everything except these words: `v1`, `key1`, `another`, `key2`**. Does anyone know how to express that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
\b(?!v1|key1|another|key2)\w+\b
```

check the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/6OWaBT/1)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do the trick

```
/\b(?!v1|key1|key2|another)\b\S+/g
```

Taken from https://www.regexpal.com/94017